# How to add a new record in java?

Tags: java

Main program:

```
System.out.print("Enter the new student name: ");
String studName = input.nextLine();
newCourse.addStudent(studName);
```

class:

```
public void addStudent(String studName){
        studentNames[noOfStudents] = studName;
        noOfStudents++;
    }
```

After run it show me this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: Use à list instead of an array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an Array, since its not expendable, you need to creat a copy of the underlying Array with one more index than the original one to put the wanted element in it.

This example uses an own method to do so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int [] start = {1,7,-4},
    added = append(start, 77);
    System.out.println("added: " + Arrays.toString(added));
  }

static public int[] append(final int[] values, final int newValue) {
  final int[] result = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length + 1);
  result[values.length] = newValue;
  return result;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays for operations like add/remove is not recommended.
Start using lists will make your life easier.
Following your example with lists

```
List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.print("Enter the new student name: ");
String studentName = input.nextLine();
students.add(studentName);

System.out.println("Number of students: " + students.size());
```